# Displaying value of tag in php code using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, css-selectors

I've started to learn CSS lately and I found a task were I need to display value of a tag car from this php code :

```
<html><head></head><body>
        <house></house>
        <star> </star>
        <car> </car>
    <car>aa test</car>
<car>aa test</car>
<car>aa test</car>
<car>aa test</car>
<car>aa test</car>
<car>aa test</car>
<car>aa test</car>
<car>aa test</car>
<car>aa test</car>
        <star> </star>
        <sun> </sun>
        <star> </star>
        <house></house>
        <car>test </car>
        <sun> </sun>
    <car>zly test</car>
<car>zly test</car>
<car>zly test</car>
<car>zly test</car>
<car>zly test</car>
<car>zly test</car>
<car>zly test</car>
<car>zly test</car>
<car>zly test</car>

    <script>
        alert(document.querySelectorAll("xxxxxxx")[0].innerHTML);
    </script>


</body></html>
```

The point is to print the value of this tag changing only content in the quotation marks in the following command :

```
alert(document.querySelectorAll("xxxxxx")[0].innerHTML);
```

I know how to display the value of a single tag but here the tag named car has a few different values. Is there any simple method to display it?

Comment: `alert(document.querySelectorAll("car")[0].innerHTML);` will display the contents of the first instance of the `<car>` tag.  Is that what you're looking for? (Note, in you're code, the alert is outside of the `<script>` tag, should move that inside).

Comment: I need to display all tags. It suppose to display:(white space), aa test, aa test... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through each item in the `querySelectorAll` array:

```
var cars = document.querySelectorAll("car");
var allCars = "";
for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    allCars += cars[i].innerHTML;
}
alert(allCars);
```

[You can see a working JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/heybignick/0u4at8we/)

Comment: is there a way to display the same without loop?

Comment: @PiotrSzczepanik I edited the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/heybignick/0u4at8we/1/) to accomplish the same without the loop but rather coercing the nodelist to an array and then using array functions.